# IAsyncResult and Multithreading in .NET 3.5

Tags: multithreading, web-services, asynchronous, .net-3.5

I'm want to make multiple requests to a remote service and I'm trying an asynchronous/multithread approach.
For the concurrent part, I'll try this http://coding-time.blogspot.pt/2008/03/implement-your-own-parallelfor-in-c.html

```
IList<string> returnedValues = new List<string>();
int numberOfRequests = 5;
object sync = new object();
ParallelUtilities.For(0, numberOfRequests, delegate(int i)
{
    string response = string.Empty;
    try
    {
         try
            {
                Func<int, string> caller = CallService;
                IAsyncResult result = caller.BeginInvoke(i, null, null);
                Thread.Sleep(0);
                string returnValue = caller.EndInvoke(result);

                lock (sync)
                {
                    returnedValues.Add(returnValue);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Concat("ex: ", ex.Message, "stack:", ex.StackTrace));
            }
    });
}
```

And the service call

```
private string CallService(int index)
{
    string value;
    using (var channel = GetClientChannel<IService>("http://localhost:51383/Service/Service.svc"))
    {
        value = channel.GetValue(index);
    }
    return value + "for this index:" + index;
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?
How do IAsyncResult works in multithreading?

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
            IAsyncResult result = caller.BeginInvoke(i, null, null);
            Thread.Sleep(0);
            string returnValue = caller.EndInvoke(result);
```

with

```
            string returnValue = CallService(result);
```

There's no point in starting code on the thread-pool and then waiting for it immediately. What would you gain by doing that? The `Sleep` is especially suspicious to me. You try to initiate a context switch which just adds additional overhead.

> How do IAsyncResult works in multithreading?

The two are not related. What do you mean?

Comment: I intend to do multiple calls to a webservice and store the results in a variable. How can I make that work with async methods and multithreading? Is that even a good implementation choice?

Comment: On 3.5, I'd use your custom `ParallelUtilities.For` (which is ok). The basic approach you are using is ok. You are running your work items on the thread-pool. Alternatively, you could use async IO but that is hard on 3.5 and likely to not help you.